# Is there any alternative to self join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have follwoing query.

```
SELECT 
   v.id,
   v.type,
   COUNT(vn.id) as notice_sent_count,
   COUNT(vn1.id) as total_count
FROM 
     vln v 
     LEFT JOIN notes vn ON(v.note_id = vn.id AND vn.note_datetime IS NOT NULL)
     LEFT JOIN notes vn1 ON(v.note_id = vn1.id)
WHERE 
     v.id = 1
GROUP BY 
     v.id,
     v.type;
```

Using self join I can acheived notice_sent_count & total count. Is there anyway to achieve same without self join. I am trying to remove 3rd join. Any idea?

```
Sample data 
------------------------------------------
v.id v.type notice_sent_count total_count
------------------------------------------
1    type1        2               5
2    type2        1               3
```

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53783537/edit) your question and show sample data and expected results only in text format, no images. Please do not expect us to reverse engineer your expected result using your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `FILTER`:

```
SELECT 
   v.id,
   v.type,
   COUNT(vn.id) FILTER (WHERE vn.note_datetime IS NOT NULL) AS notice_sent_count,
   COUNT(vn.id) AS total_count
FROM  vln v 
LEFT JOIN notes vn ON v.note_id = vn.id
WHERE v.id = 1
GROUP BY  v.id, v.type;
```

Or even simpler as [@D Stanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081897/d-stanley) suggests:

```
SELECT 
   v.id,
   v.type,
   COUNT(vn.note_datetime) AS notice_sent_count,
   COUNT(vn.id) AS total_count
FROM  vln v 
LEFT JOIN notes vn ON v.note_id = vn.id
WHERE v.id = 1
GROUP BY  v.id, v.type;
```

Comment: why not just `COUNT(vn.note_datetime)`?

Comment: @DStanley Sure, it is the most obvious way if the codtition is as simple as NOT NULL :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `CASE`:

```
SELECT 
   v.id,
   v.type,
   SUM(CASE WHEN vn.note_datetime IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS notice_sent_count,
   COUNT(vn.id) AS total_count
FROM  vln v 
LEFT JOIN notes vn ON v.note_id = vn.id
WHERE v.id = 1
GROUP BY  v.id, v.type;
```